# React having troubles creating a ticking clock that can change time manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a clock that will tick every second but also allow the user to click a button to move the clock forward an hour.

```js
    const addTime = (date, time) => new Date(date.getTime() + time)
    
    const Clock = () => {
        const [timeDate, setTimeDate] = useState(addTime(new Date(), SECOND_IN_MS));

        const updateTimeInfo = (addedTime) => {
            setTimeDate(addTime(timeDate, addedTime);
            //other info omitted, won't affect the code
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            let tickClock = setInterval(() => {
               updateTimeInfo(SECOND_IN_MS)
            }, SECOND_IN_MS);

            return () => clearInterval(tickClock);
        }, [timeDate])
    
      
        return (
            <span>{timeDate.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', hour12: true, minute: '2-digit' });</span>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => updateTimeInfo(HOUR_IN_MS)}>{"Add 1 hour"}</button>
        )
    }
```

Now the issue is because whenever I update the my clock to new a time, the useEffect is triggered and the clock is going to re-establish the interval to update every second causing the clock to not update the seconds until 1 second has passed.

I would like the clock to always tick 1 second but also allow the user to fast forward 1 hour at the same time.

Is there anyway possible to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `timeDate` dependency from the `useEffect` hook and use a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) in `updateTimeInfo`.

1. Setup interval once when the component mounts, return cleanup function to clear interval.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     const tickClock = setInterval(() => {
       updateTimeInfo(SECOND_IN_MS);
     }, SECOND_IN_MS);

     return () => clearInterval(tickClock);
   }, []);
   ```
2. The functional state update allows each enqueued `timeDate` state update to correctly update from the previous state.

   ```
   const updateTimeInfo = (addedTime) => {
     setTimeDate((timeDate) => addTime(timeDate, addedTime));
     //other info omitted, won't affect the code
   };
   ```

How it works:

The interval runs `updateTimeInfo` once per second. The button is simply also invoking `updateTimeInfo` but in an asynchronous way, i.e. whenever the +1 hour button is clicked. These two should occur independently from each other.

Without the functional state update then only the initial `timeDate` state value is closed over in the effect and time will only update each time from the initial state value.

Code

```
const SECOND_IN_MS = 1000;
const HOUR_IN_MS = 1000 * 60 * 60;

const addTime = (date, time) => new Date(date.getTime() + time);

const Clock = () => {
  const [timeDate, setTimeDate] = useState(addTime(new Date(), SECOND_IN_MS));

  const updateTimeInfo = (addedTime) => {
    setTimeDate((timeDate) => addTime(timeDate, addedTime));
    //other info omitted, won't affect the code
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const tickClock = setInterval(() => {
      updateTimeInfo(SECOND_IN_MS);
    }, SECOND_IN_MS);

    return () => clearInterval(tickClock);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <span>
        {timeDate.toLocaleTimeString([], {
          hour: "2-digit",
          hour12: true,
          minute: "2-digit",
          second: "2-digit"
        })}
      </span>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => updateTimeInfo(HOUR_IN_MS)}>
        +1 hour
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => updateTimeInfo(-HOUR_IN_MS)}>
        -1 hour
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-having-troubles-creating-a-ticking-clock-that-can-change-time-manually]

Comment: Drew, thank you so much. I am fairly new to react so I was unaware I had to do something like this: setTimeDate((timeDate) => addTime(timeDate, addedTime)) .

Comment: @NoobieProgrammer Yup, added the link to [functional state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) in my answer.